# Crusher/Destemmer care: Chain maintenance

Tags: crush

I want to take care of my crusher/destemmer and am noticing I washed off all the grease from the chain.  What lubricant can I put on that chain before I pack it up for next year?

- Bike chain lubricant?
- Olive oil?

You can sort of get a feel for the size of the chain in this product photo:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this to be a food-safe option:

http://www.petrolgel.com/

Sanitary Petro Gel from McGlaughlin Oil Company.

I reapply after each cleaning cycle (after a crush).

Answer (score 3):

- Any **oil** will prevent rust, but would not last as long as grease.  You can use a vegetable/olive oil for parts that are inside/in contact with the fruit.
- **Bike chain lube** is designed to stick to a chain that will move fast and even generate heat, so it will work as well as grease.  It come in spray so it is very easy to apply.  I would use this for the chain.
- There is also **chainsaw bar oil** that can do the job for the chain.
- Using **grease** works for the chain, but I find it a bit more messy.

Comment: Bike chain lube, or a Thick grease would be best.

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer indicates the use of grease.

> Once washing is completed, if the machine is not to be used for a long period of time, proceed as follows:
>
> 1. Open the carter that protects machine gear.
> 2. Grease all chains, internal gear, supports
> 3. Grease the roller and the agitator support

I got the info from  [here](https://morewinemaking.com/images/file.php?file_id=10430)

I wouldn't use olive oil.

Answer (score 2):

I had a crusher just like that for a long time. You want to use food grade oil or grease. You can find this easily. Olive Oil will work in a pinch. I used Weston food grade silicone spray on many different pieces of equipment from pumps to crushers. [Weston Food Grade Silicone spray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030HL3CO)

You should've spent more and got the stainless crusher model. The painted model will rust very easily.